# Show that the sets of local minima vertices in a graph, when each vertex chooses a value uniformly at random, is a $(2,O(\log n))$ ruling set

Tags: probability, graph-theory, algorithms, conditional-probability, computational-complexity

An $(\alpha,\beta)$-ruling set is a set $S$ such that any two nodes in $S$ are at distance at least $\alpha$ from each other, and, for any node $v \notin S$, there exists a node $u \in S$ such that the distance between $u$ and $v$ is at most $\beta$.

Consider the following simple 1-round randomized algorithm:

each node $v$ picks a random real number $r_v \in [0, 1]$ and then, $v$ joins a set $S$ if its random number is a local minima, that is, if $r_v < r_u$ for all neighbors $u$ of $v$.

I need to prove that, with high probability, the set $S$ is a $(2, O(\log n))$-ruling set.

Proving the $\alpha=2$ part is easy, because from the creation of $S$, only one vertex in $N(v) \cup \{v\}$ can be a local minima, and will be in $S$. Which means that the minimal distance between vertices in $S$ is $2$.

However, I can't manage to prove the $\beta$ part.

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For each vertex $v$, let $D_i$ be the number of vertices at distance $i$ from $v$. Let $m_i$ be the minimum of the labels in $D_i$.

See if you can show the following claims.

1. For any $i$, if $E_i: m_i < \min(m_1, \cdots, m_{i - 1})$ does not happen, then there is a local minima at distance at most $i$ from $v$.
2. Let $n_i = |D_i|$. Then $\mathbb{P}(E_i) = n_i / (n_0 + n_1 + \cdots + n_i)$, and the events $E_i$ are independent.
3. We have
   $$\prod_{i = 1}^{3\log_2 n} \mathbb{P}(E_i) < n^{-2}.$$

Comment: I'm not sure about the 2nd claim and 3rd claim. There is a hint in this problem that says to prove the $S \cup (N(v) \cup \{v\}) \ne \emptyset$
 for every $v \in V$ with probability at least $\frac{deg(v)+1}{deg(v)+degmax}$ (where $degmax$ is the maximal degree in $N(v)$).

Comment: Sorry there are a few typos... The event $E_i$ corresponds to the minimum of $r$ among $D_0 \cup \cdots \cup D_i$ lying in $D_i$ proper, which happens with probability $|D_i| / |D_0 \cup \cdots \cup D_i|$.

Comment: Do you know how to do the hint?

Comment: I'm having a problem calculating the conditional probability with the neighbors $N(v)$. Not sure what events to define. I can calculate $Pr[v \not \in S]$, but from there I'm stuck

Comment: I guess here is a way of thinking about the hint. Instead of assigning i.i.d random labels, consider the following process. You first generate i.i.d random numbers $x_1, \cdots, x_{deg(v) + degmax}$, and assign $x_1, ..., x_{deg(v) + 1}$ to $v$ and its neighbors. Then you look at which vertex gets the smallest label. If it is not $v$, assign $x_{deg(v) + 2}...$ to its neighbors. Finally, assign i.i.d random numbers to the unlabeled vertices

Comment: Then the resulting law of the labels should be the same as i.i.d random labels. On the other hand, if the minimum of $x_1,\cdots, x_{deg(v) + degmax}$ lies in the first $deg(v) + 1$ numbers, you have $S \cap (N(v) \cup \{v\}) \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: Does this make sense?

Comment: This makes sense overall, but don't I then get the probability $\frac{1}{deg(v)+1} + \frac{deg(v)}{deg(v)+1} \cdot \frac{1}{degmax}$?

Comment: The point is that if $x_v$ is the minimum among $x_1 ... x_{deg(v) + 1}$, it must be somewhat small. So the probability that it is the minimum among its neighbors is no longer $1 / degmax$.

Comment: I'm still not sure how to do the full computation. I think I can do the each computation independently, but it's complicated to bring them together.

Comment: Another way to see this: Consider the events $E_i$: $i$ is smallest among its neighbors and among neighbors of $v$ for each $i \in v$. The $E_i$ are disjoint and all imply $S \cap (N(v) \cup v) = \emptyset.$